# Tab Disappear when start new activity

Tags: android, tabs, android-activity, android-tabactivity

I am developing android application which having multiple tabs.

Now in launcher activity tabs display perfectly and can navigate through the tabs.
but if i call activity(which i wanted to show as Tab) on Button Clicked then tabs seems disappear.

please refer the given code and let me know if i am doing something wrong.

This is Main TabActivity

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

        TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();

        TabSpec deshTab=tabHost.newTabSpec("Deshboard");

        deshTab.setIndicator("Deshboard");
        Intent DeshboardIntent=new Intent(this,DeshboardActivity.class);
        deshTab.setContent(DeshboardIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(deshTab);


        TabSpec clientTab=tabHost.newTabSpec("client");
        clientTab.setIndicator("client");

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,ClientActivity.class);
        clientTab.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(clientTab);

    }
}
```

Now i wanted to start client activity like

```
void onButtonClick(View view)
    {
        int id = view.getId();
        switch(id)
        {
        case R.id.client_btn:

            Intent clientIntent = new Intent(DeshboardActivity.this,ClientActivity.class);
            startActivity(clientIntent);
            break;
        }   
    }
```

but when i click this button it starts new activity but NOT in tab.
what should i do to display this activity in tab on button click also.?

Below code is **ClientActivity** which i wanted to display as TAB.

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity

    {
        private DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
        private ListView clientListView ;
        private BaseAdapter listAdapter;
        TabHost tabHost;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.clientactivity);


            dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            final List<Client> clientList = dbHandler.getAllclient();

            clientListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.client_list);
            listAdapter = new ClientListAdapter(this, clientList);
            clientListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            clientListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
                {
                    Client client = clientList.get(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), client.getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent clientInfoIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClientInfoActivity.class);
                    clientInfoIntent.putExtra("client",client);
                    startActivity(clientInfoIntent);
                    //finish();

                }

            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your ClientActivity is launched on top of your TabActivity. That way your tabbar is not shown anymore.
I suggest you use fragments for your ClientActivity.

A tutorial how to use fragments:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html